# Webbrowser not opening more than 1 tab

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-webbrowser

Having an issue with my code where I want it to open all the urls from a text document all on the same browser for when I boot my pc. For some reason, when the code runs, it will open 1 page, and will open open the next when the first one has been closed.

```
import webbrowser

to_open = []

with open('sites.txt', 'r') as sites:
    for i in sites.readlines():
        to_open.append(i)

for i in to_open:
    webbrowser.open(i)
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not just configure your browser to open those tabs? All of them can these days...

Comment: Its just for a fun project...